# Isolating "braided sections" in a graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, topology

Suppose I have a graph with a graphical representation like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a "braided section", in which many different paths could be taken, but, if you keep going (at least in one direction along the main axis), you will invariably end up at the same point at the end of the "braid".

This graph could extend in either direction for a long distance and have multiple braids of arbitrary complexity along the way.

Is there some algorithm which is able to isolate the blue-circled nodes, indicating the start and the end of the "braid"? Or to go even further and just return the subgraph containing the braid, snipped at these nodes?

I am having trouble articulating this problem in Google and the documentation for my graph library doesn't explain the various algorithms it implements.

I'm currently using Python NetworkX but I am not opposed to implementing an algorithm manually if it doesn't have a direct implementation.

I should also specify that the graph could ideally be directed such that all the edges point along one direction of the major axis, but a solution that could also use an directed graph would be better.

EDIT: Here is my implementation based on the answer from @kaya3:

```
articulation_points = nx.articulation_points(graph)
for node in articulation_points:
    if nx.degree(graph, node) > 2:
        print(node)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved by finding the [articulation points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) (a.k.a. cut-vertices) of the graph; these are the vertices which, if you deleted them from the graph, then the graph would become disconnected. The set of all articulation points [can be found in linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component#Linear_time_depth_first_search) by a form of depth-first search.

It's visibly obvious that the articulation points are either the start or end of a braid, or the points along the paths between the end of one braid and the start of another. So starts and ends of braids are the articulation points which have either an out-degree or an in-degree greater than 1, respectively. (If the graph is undirected, then you want the articulation points with degree greater than 2.)

There is a special case if a braid starts immediately at the first vertex, or ends at the last vertex. In that case, it is not an articulation point but you do want to count it. So you should include the first point if its (out-)degree is more than 1, and the last point if its (in-)degree is more than 1.

Comment: I jumped the gun on the previous answer, this one is much more succint, and also covers the case if there are many pseudonodes throughout the graph.

Comment: Actually there is another caveat with this solution, I failed to be specific enough with my requirements - I actually want to find the braided **interval**. While this does get my the points at which the intervals start and stop, I'm not sure to differentiate where along the graph is inside or outside of the braid, especially when many pseudonodes are present, like in the example.

Comment: I see. One solution would be to delete the articulation points which are not starts or ends of braids, and then find the connected components. That is also linear time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a specific algorithm that does this, but implementing one is easy enough. You iterate over your nodes breadth-first and keep track of the number of branches you're exploring. When the number increases above 1, you're at the start of a "braid". When the number of simultaneous branches you're exploring goes down to 1, you've just found the end of a braid. This may not be optimal as your complexity is greater than O(n) since you can't skip nodes already visited if you have a different number of nodes in your various branches (if you did, you might skip the end of the braid), but unless you're dealing with millions of nodes, a high branching factor and big imbalances, I expect you should be fine.

Comment: Perfect, such a simple and elegant solution that was eluding me. It also works on undirected graphs.

Comment: On undirected graphs it has a problem, because when you reach the end of a "braid" where two branches meet, but the two branches didn't reach the end at the same time, then it would start exploring the other branch backwards. That would be indistinguishable from branching in two forwards directions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use also betweenness centrality since it is a good measure of the number of shortest paths that go through a node. The node that initiates a branch or closes it should have a high betweenness centrality over the others. This of course is not exact as a complex behaviour inside the braids could result in some nodes inside it having also a high betweenness centrality but I think is a fast approach (as it is already implemented, the function can take a long time if you have a lot of nodes) that may yield the result you are expecting for.